# How to turn off checking digital signature for XLL add-ins?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to make Excel load unsigned XLL add-ins without showing any security prompts. How can I do that?

Comment: What's the Excel version?

Comment: it's Excel 2010

Answer (score 1):

This [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857086.aspx) article should explain how to enable/disable plugin security settings, including for XLL files and the ramifications of the changes. In particular, disabling security notifications is explained in [this section](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857086.aspx#disablenotifications).

Comment: Disabling notifications as described there completely prevents all unsigned XLLs from running. You really think this is an answer to the question asked?